# Relation between generics type in Java

Tags: java, generics

Please, consider my code:

```
interface AInterface {}

interface BInterface extends AInterface {}

class AClass implements AInterface { }

class BClass extends AClass implements BInterface {}

class Descriptor<S extends AClass, T extends AInterface> {

    private Class<S> classClass;

    private Class<T> interfaceClass;

    public Descriptor(Class<S> classClass, Class<T> interfaceClass) {
        this.classClass = classClass;
        this.interfaceClass = interfaceClass;
    }
}

class Foo {

    public void test() {
        Descriptor<AClass, BInterface> descriptor = 
               new Descriptor<>(AClass.class, BInterface.class);//LINE X
    }
}
```

So, I have two interfaces and two classes that implement them. And I have a descriptor to which I must add two classes - the class of the interface and class of the implementation. The question is how to add relation restrict between them. I mean, that at `LINE X` I must get compilation error, because `AClass` doesn't implement `BInterface`. How to do it?

Comment: I think you're asking a lot out of Java generics haha. I'm not entirely sure this is possible in this case, as you are enforcing multiple type bounds on `S`. I'm also not sure it's impossible but I have my doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think this is possible. Enforcing multiple type bounds is possible when all of them but the first one (optionally) are interfaces, but I'm unaware of any trick allowing to do it for multiple classes. Here's how it works for interfaces:

```
public class Bar {}
public class Baz extends Bar {}
public class Foo1<T extends Bar & Serializable> {}                   // compiles
public class Foo2<T extends Serializable & Bar> {}                   // doesn't compile
public class Foo2<T extends Bar & Baz> {}                            // doesn't compile
public class Foo3<T extends Serializable & Closeable> {}             // compiles
public class Foo4<T extends Serializable & Closeable & Runnable> {}  // compiles
```

What's your real use case? Perhaps there's a way to approach the problem differently.

Comment: Note that it is not possible to extend both classes `Bar` and `Baz`, nit just to test it. There can be no type extending both classes.

Comment: It's possible in a linear inheritance tree (`Foo extends Bar` and `Bar extends Baz`). The answer is not about this, it's about whether you can enforce two type bounds on the same type

Comment: Yes but this would make no sense as it would be an instance of the parent class in any way.

Comment: That's beyond the point, that's what I'm trying to get through here. The OP wants to enforce that `S` is both a subtype of `AClass` and a subtype of `T`, which is perfectly possible in various inheritance trees, but the question is whether or not you can setup generics to enforce those boundaries